# Neo4j query takes an eternity to execute

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My code takes an eternity to compute jaccard similarity. It is an .csv file with 100000 in it. I have already created indexes on 2 basic Nodes (id+ value)
I have already use the Jaccard algorithm in Playground but it also takes an eternity to run.

```
MATCH (i:Item)-[:HAS]->(p2:Properties)<-[:HAS]-(i1:Item)
WITH {item:id(i), categories: collect(id(i1))} as userData
WITH collect(userData) as data
CALL algo.similarity.jaccard.stream(data, {similarityCutoff: 0.5})
YIELD item1, item2, count1, count2, intersection, similarity
RETURN algo.asNode(item1).id AS from, algo.asNode(item2).id AS to, intersection, similarity
```

Can anyone help?
[image]

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the indices you created are not exercised here (there are only `NodeByLabelScan`).
You should make sure that `i1` does not refer to the same node as `i` (do you need every permutation possible or only distinct pairs)?

Comment: @fbiville thank you very much for your response can i simply adjust it by i1 <> i ?

Comment: @user12678036, your are comparing each Items by looking at how each item is similar to another item via Properties. So the userData should be like {item, collect(properties)} and NOT {item1, collect(item2)} because you look at item->properties NOT between items. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two lines syntax of your query is not correct. You should run it like this:

```
OLD: 
MATCH (i:Item)-[:HAS]->(p2:Properties)<-[:HAS]-(i1:Item)
WITH {item:id(i), categories: collect(id(i1))} as userData

NEW: 
MATCH (i:Item)-[:HAS]->(p2:Properties)
WITH {item:id(i), categories: collect(id(p2))} as userData
```

This is what the algorithm (jaccard ) is doing. An item (say Item1) is similar (number from 0 to 1 inclusive) to another item (like Item2) if both shares the same properties.  For example; Item1 has 3 properties1,2,3 and Item2 has 3 properties2,3,4. So the jaccard similarity index is 2/4 or 0.5 because property2,3 are common and there are 4 unique properties in both items.

> So in your query, you only need to specify that an item (like item1) has some properties and you don't need to specify another item (like item2) has some properties. The function will iterate all items and will give you the jaccard index, that is, item1 vs item2, item1 vs item3..., item2 vs item3, so on...This is the syntax for algo.similarity.jaccard.stream.

See reference here: https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/labs-algorithms/jaccard/

Comment: if i do this, neo4j returns a black screen... of course I re-started over and over again. I have a machine with 32GB RAM in it...

Comment: migrated in 4.2 and no longer had memory problems

Comment: if the query works now, please accept my answer and upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: I ran it in playground. But I'll check this and accept your answer :)